# how use xpath i select radio button with different id, value but same name?

Tags: xpath, radio-button

This are my codes. are there ways to select the radio button using xpath by the name or the values? i don't want use the id to select the button.

```
<tr class="rowOdd">
<td style="width:25">
<div id="uniform-fileRefSysId_3" class="radio">
<span>
<input id="fileRefSysId_3" type="radio" value="3" onclick="javascript:setFileRef(this.id);" name="fileRef"/>
</span>
</div>
<input id="fileRefTitle_3" type="hidden" value="CLT-02"/>
<input id="fileRefNo_3" type="hidden" value="CLT-02"/>
</td>
<td>Consultant</td>
<td>CLT-02</td>
<td>CLT-02</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//*[@name="fileRef"]`

Please include the approaches you have already tried and why they failed next time.

Comment: i was previously trying out using value and id cause i was looping through. it works now! thanks bro!